# How do I set a toggle based on the end of a string

Tags: expansion, etoolbox, xstring

Compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring}

\newcommand{\strendswithfoo}{\IfEndWith{bar-foo}{foo}{true}{false}}

\newtoggle{strendswithfoo}
\settoggle{strendswithfoo}{\strendswithfoo}

\begin{document}

command \textbackslash strendswithfoo = \strendswithfoo

toggle strendswithfoo = \iftoggle{strendswithfoo}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```

leads to the following errors:

```
./test.tex:7: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.7 \settoggle{strendswithfoo}{\strendswithfoo}

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.


./test.tex:7: Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 \settoggle{strendswithfoo}{\strendswithfoo}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{\@firstoftwo {\let \@xs@assign \@xs@expand@and@detokenize \@xs@IfEndWith@@ \ETC.
./test.tex:7: Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.7 \settoggle{strendswithfoo}{\strendswithfoo}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

./test.tex:7: Package etoolbox Error: Invalid boolean value '\let \reserved@d =*\def \par .
<recently read>  

l.7 \settoggle{strendswithfoo}{\strendswithfoo}

Valid boolean values are 'true' and 'false'.
```

The output document contains:

```
command \strendswithfoo = true
toggle strendswithfoo = false
```

I would like the toggle `strendswithfoo` to be true. Happy to switch away from xstring if there is a better solution.

Comment: As with almost any `xstring` macro: They are not expandable. Switching to a `expl3` based solution is better, in my point of view

Answer (score 2):

A different approach using `listofitems`, whose results are expandable.  That is to say, the actual `\readlist` is not expandable, but the array of data it produces is expandable.

In this implementation, I search the test string for all occurrences of "foo", using it as a list separator.  The text that *isn't* "foo" is stored in the `\foosep` array, `\foosep[1]`, `\foosep[2]`, etc. where the index `1` is the text to the left of the leftmost "foo", the index `2` is the text between the 1st and 2nd "foo", etc.

Negative indices such as `[-1]` merely starts the counting leftward, from the rightmost "foo".  If the string ended in "foo", then the expansion of `\foosep[-1]`, representing the text to the right of the rightmost "foo", will be empty, and so I test its emptiness to determine whether to set the toggle to true or false.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,listofitems}

\newtoggle{strendswithfoo}
\def\toggletmp{\settoggle{strendswithfoo}}

\newcommand{\teststrendswithfoo}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{foo}%
  \readlist\foosep{#1}%
  \edef\strendswithfoo{\if\relax\foosep[-1]\relax{true}\else{false}\fi}%
  \expandafter\toggletmp\strendswithfoo
}

\begin{document}
\teststrendswithfoo{bar-foo}
toggle strendswithfoo = \iftoggle{strendswithfoo}{true}{false}

\teststrendswithfoo{foo-bar}
toggle strendswithfoo = \iftoggle{strendswithfoo}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make the arguments to `\IfEndWith` `\toggletrue` and `\togglefalse`. I find this rather unsatisfying and a little more like spaghetti code than I'd like but it is short.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring}

\newtoggle{strendswithfoo}

\IfEndWith{bar-foo}{foo}{\toggletrue}{\togglefalse}{strendswithfoo}

\begin{document}

toggle strendswithfoo = \iftoggle{strendswithfoo}{true}{false}

\end{document}
```